# New resync after a complete reindex

Tags: bitcoind, full-node, bitcoin-cli, nodes, reindex

After an error with LevelDB (corrupted) I did a reindex and after that bitcoind automatically start a new synchronization. This seems much faster some times, it started from genesis and in 1 hour it reached 2015 but it seems strange to me that it's doing a resynchronization... Can anyone tell me if this is normal? Thanks in advance

Comment: With new “synchronization” do you mean it did a _rescan_, or do you mean that it immediately did another _reindex_? Did you add `reindex=1` to your node configuration? If so, it would do it on every startup.

Comment: After the reindex process, it immediately starts with a new sync of the blockchain like the first installation of the node... I do not have this string in my .conf because following a guide I used `txindex = 1`. I am going to edit it but now what I have to do with this? I have to stop it? Thanks

Comment: `txindex` means that your node keeps an index of where each transaction is found in your blockchain data. It should have no bearing on your reindexing issue. Could you please check the log and see whether there was some information between finishing the first reindex and starting the resync then?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I no longer have the logs from 24 hours ago, the last one is from this morning but I was at the console when the reindex finished and didn't notice any errors... Could it be a reindex phase? I'll try to explain better: Immediately after the reindex, the same message appeared in the log that appeared during the sync phase with the progress, height and other info... What do you think? Thanks for your patience